# replace existing menu programtically

Tags: menus

I create my own menu programatically:

```
    $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu($menu_name);
    wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
        'menu-item-title' =>  __('Home'),
        'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
        'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/' ),
        'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

    wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
        'menu-item-title' =>  __('Custom Page'),
        'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/custom/' ),
        'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

    wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
        'menu-item-title' =>  __('SHIT'),
        'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/custom/' ),
        'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
```

Now i can to replace my menu with the existing one. What code should i call?
Thanks
From Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to `functions.php` of your current theme ( preferably child theme ):

```
$menuName = 'Your menu name';
$locationID = 'primary';
$myMenu = get_term_by('name', $menuName, 'nav_menu');
$locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');
if($myMenu->term_id !== $locations[$locationID]) {
    $locations[$locationID] = $myMenu->term_id;
    set_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations', $locations);
}
```

Remember to change values of first two variables to match your requirements.